# Write tab-separated array to screen?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, io, julia

`writedlm` is very convenient to write a matrix to a file. Is there a way to do something similar, to write a vector to the console?
Doing `println` will also print the `[`,`]` and the comma. I just want to write the tab-separated values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
writedlm(STDOUT,mat)
```

`writedlm` can also write to buffers and anything which is a subtype of type `IO`.